# cannot view Windows XP in boot menu

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows-xp

I have windows Xp and Win 7 and ubuntu 12 installed in different partitions. but i am able to boot to ubuntu and windows 7 but cannot see windows XP partions in boot menu.

please help me to add it in ubuntu boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance did you install windows after installing ubuntu? This is probably what happened...

I would try using "boot repair". For all my boot problems the default setting has worked for me. From blank grub screens on a 12 year old computer to booting from a windows 7 install on a brand new laptop.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Basically you will boot from a live dvd/usb (or if you can boot to umbuntu from your hard drive) and install boot-repair via this command:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

and select recommended repair. It will uninstall and reinstall grub, so if windows removed it, this will fix it.

You might also look at this article:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows